# IOS: use navigation controller in a subview

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

In a view of my program I have a button and with this button I open a subview; this subview is a view with a tableview. I want go to another view when I push a row of the tableview so I want to make this with a navigation controller; how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view delegate will receive a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message when you click on one of the table's rows.

You can put there your code to create the UINavigationController and push on to it your new view.

This sample code (from another [answer of mine on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174914/how-to-show-uinavigationcontroller-on-view/6175129#6175129)) shows how you can do that:

```
 UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 iVkViewController *overviewViewController = [[iVkViewController alloc] init];
 overviewViewController.title = @"First";
 [navigation pushViewController:overviewViewController animated:NO];
```

This should help you getting things on track.

One side note: you might think of having a navigation controller from the very start, this would make your UI more "well-behaved", but this depends ultimately on your app requirements.

Comment: then I make a file with a tableview delegate methods, after i write your code inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I have a navigation controller? and the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, my example does not refer to a UITableViewController, but to pushing a generic view (as per your question) on to the navigation controller. If this is another table view, you will need to deal with it as you have already done for the other that you have. Actually, you could also define your table view and its controller in a new nib file and load this in the code above, it's up to you. The navigation controller by default manages a navigation bar that allows you to go back, so you don't need to do anything special with the navigation bar (unless you wish to customize it).

Comment: no I want first subview where is a tableview and when i push a row of this table view I go to the second subview (but this isn't a tableview)

Comment: sorry, I misread your comment. you were right, you need a delegate, and you will also need create a new view with its view controller (what you want to push on to the controller), and the my code will do the trick (including navigation bar). in case you have problems, give details...

Comment: have you any examples to make it?

Comment: what you should do is the same you already did for your first view. it's pretty hard to give an example of a view/controller I don't know anything about... how did you create the first view?

Comment: look this example: http://www.2shared.com/file/uSr0x2PL/simple_table.html I want to do a similar but in a subview

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by doing similar in a subview? Why does the code I provided not fit your needs? Where is the problem? What is your blocking point?

Comment: This example refers to an application starting where the navigation controller is set  in appDelegate, but now I do not have to set the navigation controller in appdelegate But this simple table must be my subview in my program. that's all

Comment: If you want it as a subview, you can add it to the main view using: `[view addSubview:tableView];` and you don't need to deal with the navigation controller.

Comment: no we do not understand yet, I know how to add a normal subView But I do not know how to add a subview as "simple table"

Comment: indeed, it is difficult to understand. "simple table" is an app, made of many views and controllers? you would like to embed it as a whole in a view? if your question is how you can have a navigation controller that is not set at the top of the display, I fear that this is not possible. The default navigation bar provided by Apple is fixed.

Comment: image program without a navigation controller, but a simple program with a view, in this view there is a button and when I press this button I want you to appear  a subview as ​​"simple table", is it clare?

Comment: You can load a nib as a subview. Is this what you want to do? Again: simple table is a full program, you cannot have it shown as a subview.

Comment: then if I have a simply view and push a button I can't show a subview made as simple_table...right?

Comment: no, because simple table is not just a view/subview, is more complex than that and you need to "copy" every single entity in simple_table in your program and manage it individually. the nib is the largest component that you can try and "reuse" as such. you have to build your UI piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

If UIViewController addSubView a view of UITableViewController,you want to push in the method of tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath,you should check if     self.navigationController is nil. If it's nil,You probably should use

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

if self.parentViewController is also nil,Sometimes,you have to set a @property to point out the parentViewController In UITableViewController,like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *parentVC;
```

and in UIViewController:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewVC = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewVC.parentVC = self;
```

In UITableViewController ,-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[self.parentVC.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```